# Optimization of the Regex?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, boost-regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

Hi guys I am new to the regex for some patterns matching i have wrote the regex but it is very lengthy regex so i was hoping that any one can help me optimize it ?

My REGEX-->

```
(T)(\d{9})(T)(\s{0,19}\d{0,19}\s{0,19}[0-9DO ]\d{0,19}\s{0,19}[OD0-9 ]\s{0,19}\d{0,19}\s{0,19}\d{0,19}[0-9D ]\d{0,19})(O)(\s{0,5}\d{0,19})\b
```

Pattern I want to match -->

```
T062102098T0741 0361212401O
T011900571T 000007250107O1274
T065000090T203 93 5797 9O 4037  
T325170628T0108626004D18O01054
T071108452T    42D896D5O 3587 
T041211609T 01D1270DD4O 2721
T021407912TO9196D00580D6O 7106
T081219108T O45D936D4O 3155
T074909988T O022D853 6O 1340
```

Pattern I am avoiding -->

```
T071904779T154505122619 2051
T065000090T000 32 493O9O 11007
```

So any help would be great .Thanks in advance.

Comment: On what logic are you matching or avoiding patterns? Or do you expect us to deduce that from your (illegible) pattern? Or maybe guess it from the examples?

Comment: Not an answer, hence the comment but if I where you I'd leave it as it is... The expression you have seems to be working and seems to be relatively self explanatory, which is a lot when talking about a regular expression.

Comment: @npinti The expression is **horrible**, the `\s{0,19}\d{0,19}\s{0,19}\d{0,19}` bit makes no sense. I would take it outside and shoot it and start again.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: I never said it was great. Regarding certain sections, I was assuming that these could be explained by more examples of what is the expression supposed to match or not match,

Comment: After Second "T" character there is varies combinations of the numbers ,white spaces and the  alphabets which consist in 19 places before "O" character and after that 8 character combination of the spaces and numbers

Comment: Chapter 6 of the classic work: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "By Jeffrey Friedl. Best book on Regex - ever!") focuses on how to write an efficient regex (which needs to be fast for both matching and not matching). For starters, adding `^` and `$` anchors may speed up the case where the pattern does not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RegEx is fine, rather it could be simplified (perhaps optimized) as below:

```
(?x)
   (
      (?:T\d{9})
      (?:T\s*\d{0,19}\s*[0-9DO ]\d{0,19}\s*[OD0-9 ]\s*\d{0,19}\s*\d{0,19}[0-9D ]\d{0,19})
      (?:O\s*\d{0,19})
      \b
   )
```

One thing I have found in your RegEx, is unnecessary use of `(...)`. Moreover, using `\s{0,19}` or `\s{0,5}` could be simply written as `\s*`. The last one is better, only if you're not restricted to use of `0-19` times or `0-5` times.